# Finding horizontal asymptotes

Tags: calculus, limits

So I have to find the horizontal asympottes of

$$
f(x)=(\sqrt{x^2+1}-|x|)(x+2)
$$

Relatively straightforward. For the limit at infinity, the absolute value I turn into a positive and solve it and I get 1/2 which is correct.

But for the negative infinity portion, I get division by 0 if I simplify and "plug in" infinity.

I'm not allowed to use L'Hopital's rule on this. I rationalized it as normal but I end of getting:

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{ x+2 }{ \sqrt{x^2+1}-x }
$$

But if I got ahead and simplify that, I get get $$1/0$$
which is clearly undefined. Any ideas?

I used the assumption that I turn the absolute value negative as it goes to negative infinity. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As $x\to -\infty$ we have that: 
$$f(x) = \left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)(x+2)= \frac{\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)(x+2)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}=\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}.$$
Thus, $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)\begin{array}[t]{l} = \lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\dfrac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}=\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\dfrac{x+2}{-x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+1\right)}\\[3ex]
=\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\dfrac{x}{-x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+1\right)}+\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\dfrac{2}{-x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+1\right)}\\[3ex]
=-\dfrac 12  +0  =-\dfrac 12.
\end{array}
$$

---

As $x\to -\infty$:

$\sqrt{x^2+1} - x=\sqrt{x^2\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}-x =|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}} - x =-x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}-x = -x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+1\right)$

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I did to get 1/2 but the -1/2 part does not work when I do the same thing.

Comment: I ALMOST did what you did but on the denominator I factored out an x instead of a -x. Is that wrong?

Comment: OMG, I completely forgot about that! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!